# Ball in hand on the black - where can it go?

Tags: rules, pool

If I made a foul (such as scratching the cue ball), my opponent has the ball in hand.

Where can they place it, if they are on the black?

Answer (score -2):

Playing with BCA/APA rules the ball  can be placed anywhere on the table.

Comment: Can you refer directly to a rule for this? Preferably, citing the rules document also.